# OCT 1st deadline and fbs_xxx cookie

Tags: web-applications, facebook

I have a lil confusion regarding the changes for OCT 1st deadline. I am using FB Connect on my site and obtaining the accesstoken from the cookie $_COOKIE['fbs_xxxxx']. Do I need to change this? because according to my understanding signed_request is only available to canvas apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to migrate to oauth 2.0, this means use oauth:true in javascript SDK:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/
```

which is responsible for the cookie, new cookie name will be fbsr_APP_ID instead of fbs_APP_ID.
You have to support it on a website as well as on canvas apps.

In addition canvas apps have to support SSL, websites don't have to.

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Anatoly, I will just check if this works. Seems quite logical to me though

Comment: it helped and I am decrypting the fbsr_APP_ID cookie the same way as signed_request is decypted. but now I am getting code instead of oauth_token. :s

Comment: you can exchange this code for access token see docs for authentication.

Comment: keeps on returning the error {"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code.","type":"OAuthException"}}